# How does browser solidity differentiate calls from transactions with the abi?

Tags: remix

It's all in the question.

I've noticed that there is a color difference for Transact/Transact(Payable)/Call

I would like to know if there is a javascript script to do that ? or i'd need calculate the gas cost for each function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean this 
[image: color legend browser solidity] the ABI says it all.

Taking my contract Matthew.sol as an example:

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getNewPeriod","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeriod","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"stake","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getBlocksTillMatthew","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getDestroyedWhenRoundOver","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"whale","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"destroyWhenRoundOver","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newPeriod","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setNewPeriod","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"blockheight","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"msg","type":"string"},{"indexed":false,"name":"winner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"blocknumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"MatthewWon","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"msg","type":"string"},{"indexed":false,"name":"staker","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"blocknumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"StakeIncreased","type":"event"}]
```

take the first function:

```
 {"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getNewPeriod","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}
```

If `"constant":true` then the function is a call. A call is a read only function, because it doesn't alter the blockchain you can call it without spending gas, it won't be mined and it is executed locally on your node only. Thus is fast and cheap.

If `"constant":false` it is a transaction. It needs to be mined and costs gas executed on all mines and its slow. Now you see `"payable":false` telling you can't send money to it.